# Ionic Framework textarea keyboard scroll issue after Apple Testflight processing

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, testflight

We are using the ionic framework with iOS.

In the iOS emulator and in Safari browser, for one of our pages, clicking in a textarea shows the keyboard, and scrolls the textarea upwards so it is still viewable.

When the app is archived and processed through Apple iOS TestFlight, the behaviour is changed. Now, clicking in a textarea shows the keyboard, but the textarea no longer scrolls upwards so it is hidden.

Looks like something in the archival process is causing an issue.

Here's the code (there's another div above it). There's only the one textarea.

```
  <div ng-if="!dy_compl">
<div class="wi-bottom item ">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, dy) in element.dys">
    <div id="wi-scroll-div" ng-if="key == dySel" style="height: {{scroller_height}}; overflow: scroll;">
      <div>
        <style>
          p.wi-icon:before {
            background: url("img/old_building.png") no-repeat !important;
          }
        </style>
        <p class="wi-icon" ng-bind-html="dy.intro | to_trusted"></p>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="dy.ref">
        <p class="wi-intro-my3" ng-bind-html="dy.ref.intro | to_trusted"></p>
        <div ng-repeat="data in dy.ref.data track by $index">
          <p class="wi-intro-my3-table" style="margin-left: 5%;" ng-bind-html="data | to_trusted"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label id="wi-input" class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label" style="width:100%; max-width: 100%;">
        <div class="wi-bottom-input-label" ng-bind-html="dy.notelabel | to_trusted"></div>
      </span>
        <textarea class="wi-bottom-input" ng-model="dy.note" type="text" placeholder="{{dy.note}}" ng-style="{'background-color': textAreaBackgroundColor}"></textarea>
      </label>
      <button class="wi-bottom-button button button-assertive col text-center" ng-click="dy.saved=true;saveNow()">
        Save Notes
      </button>
      </br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you use a keyboard plugin? I think it should manage this automatically. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard

Comment: We use this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard. It's proving to be content sensitive as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that we had one view that was manually disabling the keyboard scroll using:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true)
```

We weren't re-enabling this on a switch to another view.

The result is that in the emulator, the scroll disabling didn't traverse the scope to the new page, whereas after archival and TestFlight, it did.

Thanks for the other answers, comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make it work with the plugin, check out this code I used on one project.. Looks a bit overhead, but it works:

Template:

```
<ion-content scroll-handle="user-profile-scroll">
    <textarea maxlength="160" ng-model="currentUser.bio" ng-readonly="!editMode || focusAddInterestInput" placeholder="Write your bio..." class="user-bio"><    </textarea>
</ion-content>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
$scope.keyboardHeight = 0;

$scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function() {

    var scrollView = {scrollTo: function() { console.log('Could not resolve scroll delegate handle'); }};

    $timeout(function() {

        var instances = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('user-profile-scroll')._instances;
        instances.length && (scrollView = instances[instances.length - 1]);

    }).then(function() {

        $scope.unbindShowKeyboardHandler = $scope.$on('KeyboardWillShowNotification', function(evt, info) {

            $scope.keyboardHeight = info.keyboardHeight;

            var input = angular.element(document.activeElement);
            var body = angular.element(document.body);
            var top = input.prop('offsetTop');
            var temp = angular.element(input.prop('offsetParent'));
            var tempY = 0;

            while (temp && typeof(temp.prop('offsetTop')) !== 'undefined') {

                tempY = temp.prop('offsetTop');
                top += tempY;
                temp = angular.element(temp.prop('offsetParent'));

            }

            top = top - (scrollView.getScrollPosition().top || 0);

            var inputHeight = input.prop('offsetHeight');

            var requiredSroll = $scope.windowHeight - $scope.keyboardHeight > top + inputHeight + 11 ? 0 : $scope.windowHeight - $scope.keyboardHeight - top - inputHeight - 12;

            $timeout(function(){ scrollView.scrollTo(0, - requiredSroll || 0, true); });

        });

        $scope.unbindHideKeyboardHandler = $scope.$on('KeyboardWillHideNotification', function(evt, info) {
                                                              console.log(evt, info);
            $scope.keyboardHeight = 0;

            $timeout(function() { scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0, true); });

        });

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {

            $scope.unbindShowKeyboardHandler();
            $scope.unbindHideKeyboardHandler();

        });

    });
});
```

andm finally in app.js:

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(info){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('KeyboardWillShowNotification', info);
}

function keyboardHideHandler(info){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('KeyboardWillHideNotification', info);
}
```